# Remove notification when force close message occured

Tags: android, android-emulator

Im displaying a notification when app running. For any reason app showed force close message, which closes the app after clicking the force close button, I need to remove the app icon from notification area.

Please guide me hw i can do this.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend not crashing your app in the first place. At the very least, add proper exception handling (but really, just fix your bugs).

If you absolutely cannot avoid crashes for whatever obscure reason, use an exception handler (`Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`).

Answer (score 2):

If you're handling this inside of a `Service` a solution that worked best for me was to kill all notifications when the service is created.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  mNM.cancelAll();
}
```

I had been running into problems when the notification would stay running even after a force close. I initially had my `cacnelAll()` method in the `onDestroy()` but I found out that `onDestroy()` doesn't necessarily get called. The safest bet is to cancel the notifications you have running in both the `onDestroy` and `onCreate` methods.

Answer (score 1):

If your notifications are handled by a service and target API is 14 or higher then you have an opportunity to cancel notifications in overriden "void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)" method.